# Add a title to a JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable which is created using a TableModel `JTable t = new JTable(tableModel)` I want to add a title to it. I was hoping for something like `t.setTitle(graphTitle);` but i cant find anything on that lines. I dont mind if the title is on top or below the table.
I was using JLabels but it just looks messy.

Can anyone help?
Cheers in advance

Comment: Placing a JLabel above the JScrollPane containing the JTable looks like the best and easiest solution to me. Why does it look messy?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Another option you could consider is enclosing the `JTable` in a `JPanel` and setting a `TitledBorder` to that `JPanel`.

Like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TableTitle
{
    public TableTitle ()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame ();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        panel.setBorder (BorderFactory.createTitledBorder (BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder (),
                                                            "Table Title",
                                                            TitledBorder.CENTER,
                                                            TitledBorder.TOP));


        JTable table = new JTable (3, 3);

        panel.add (table);

        frame.add (panel);

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
        frame.pack ();
        frame.setVisible (true);
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater (new Runnable ()
        {
            @Override public void run ()
            {
                TableTitle t = new TableTitle ();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: @kleopatra I didn't really focus on that. Just wanted to make the program work :) .

Comment: basics should be correct without needing to focus on them ;-) Or in other words: please edit your example

Comment: -1 for null Layout (late, probably didn't see it earlier due to the eye hurting naming - +1 for cleaning those up ;-)

Comment: @kleopatra -1 and + 1 equals 0. So why -1 ? Yes, I know null-layout is bad, I was in the habit of constantly using it. I got out of it lately, it wasn't easy :D .

Comment: as an incentive to edit, again :-) Errors have a fatal tendency to propagate ... see f.i. another typical and maybe equally frequent mistake http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11464791/how-to-add-image-in-jpanel

Comment: @kleopatra OK, I fixed it :) . I should check to see if I posted something similar in the past.

Comment: cool - now on to remove the setPreferredSize. Yeah, I'm trying to drive you to churn out the best :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I know that `setPreferredSize` is the way to go, layout managers rely on it to draw stuff. What do you consider to be a better alternative ?

Comment: the table cares for itself - why do you want to interfere? As to why/what/not related to setXXSize: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi/7229519#7229519

Comment: @kleopatra Done :) . I will try to read that question and all those links. This topic on layout managers is one that is very poorly covered (from a best-practice point-of-view) and it can be super easy to fail at doing things right.

Answer (score 2):

You would have to add it when you instantiate your DefaultTableModel:

```
String data[][] = {{"Vinod","MCA","Computer"},
{"Deepak","PGDCA","History"},
{"Ranjan","M.SC.","Biology"},
{"Radha","BCA","Computer"}};

String col[] = {"Name","Course","Subject"};

DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,col);
table = new JTable(model);
```

If it already exists, you can do something like this:

```
ChangeName(table,0,"Stu_name");
ChangeName(table,2,"Paper");

public void ChangeName(JTable table, int col_index, String col_name){
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(col_index).setHeaderValue(col_name);
}
```

Courtesy of [RoseIndia.net](http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/swing/ChangeColumnName.shtml)

Hope that helps.

Comment: that's not what the OP asked for (which was _table_ title, not _column_ title

Answer (score 2):

You can also add your title the JScrollPane which inscribes jtable in it.

**Code:**

```java
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder ("Table Title"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have much options here. JTable has no functionality to add a titlebar.
So using JLabel or other components is your only option.
Try putting the JTable in a JTabbedPane.