# how to add Image in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I add a tabbedpane in my frame and call tab.add(" ",new Img()) that extends Img with JPanel ..

The question is: Could I add JScrollPane in that JPanel and drawImage as JPanel's background and also to do additional drawing on that image such as making route on background image(such as map) because I want to apply Prim's algorithm on those route...

And also if I wish to add additional panel on tabbedpane like above, how could I control those tab actions..

The sample code is like that...

If you have any idea on Prim's algorithm and graph algorithm please help me!
Thanks!

```
public class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    private JMenu menuFile = new JMenu();
    private JMenuItem menuFileExit = new JMenuItem();
    private JPanel jPanel1 = new JPanel();
    private JLabel lbl1=new JLabel();
    private JLabel lbl2=new JLabel();
    private JPanel jPanel2 = new JPanel();
    private JTabbedPane jTabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
    private JPanel originalgraph = new JPanel();
    private JPanel zebuthiri = new JPanel();
    private JPanel dekhinathiri = new JPanel();
    private JPanel oattayathiri = new JPanel();
    private JPanel pobbathiri = new JPanel();
    private JPanel zeyathiri = new JPanel();
    int weight[][] = null;
    public MainFrame(int [][]w) {
        this.weight=w;
        try {
            jbInit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void jbInit() throws Exception {
        this.setJMenuBar( menuBar );
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
        Toolkit tk=getToolkit();
        Dimension size=tk.getScreenSize();
        this.setSize( new Dimension(size) );
        this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        menuFile.setText( "File" );
        menuFileExit.setText( "Exit" );
        menuFileExit.addActionListener( new ActionListener() { public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent ae ) { fileExit_ActionPerformed( ae ); } } );
        jPanel1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 160));
        jPanel1.setLayout(null);
        lbl1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 160));
        lbl1.setIcon(new ImageIcon("5.jpg"));
        lbl2.setIcon(new ImageIcon("b.jpg"));
        jPanel2.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 630, 1365, 160));
        lbl2.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 1365, 160));
        jPanel2.setLayout(null);
        jTabbedPane1.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 160, 1365, 470));

        menuFile.add( menuFileExit );
        menuBar.add( menuFile );
        jPanel1.add(lbl1);
        jPanel2.add(lbl2);


        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Zebu Thiri",new zebuthiri(weight));
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Original Graph",new originalgraph(weight));
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Dekhina Thiri",new dekhinathiri(weight));
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Oattaya Thiri",new oattayathiri(weight));
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Pobba Thiri",new pobbathiri(weight));
        jTabbedPane1.addTab("Zeya Thiri",new zeyathiri(weight));
        this.getContentPane().add(jTabbedPane1, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanel2, null);
        this.getContentPane().add(jPanel1, null);
    }

    void fileExit_ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int w[][]=new int [100][100];
        MainFrame f=new MainFrame(w);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

please read [How to add an image to a JPanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299495/java-swing-how-to-add-an-image-to-a-jpanel?rq=1)

in small lines the image can be added on JPanel like this

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel{

    private BufferedImage image;

    public ImagePanel() {
       try {                
          image = ImageIO.read(new File("image name and path"));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
            // handle exception...
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null); 
                    // see javadoc for more info on the parameters
    }
}
```

In the example above the image is loaded in the constructor of the class and it is then drawn by the `paintComponent(...)` which is called by default after executing the constuctor

Comment: 1) A simpler solution would be to use a JLabel with an ImageIcon. It also takes care of the asynchronous loading of the image. 2) _paintComponent(...) which is called by default after executing the constuctor_ This is clearly an incorrect statement. `paintComponent` is eventually called by the RepaintManager (or if you call one of the paintXXX method yourself) when required (ie, when a repaint event comes on the Event queue).3) Always print the stacktrace of the exception (to a log if preferred). Not logging a stacktrace can be a nightmare to debug code

Comment: -1 for copying an _incorrect_ implementation ;-) Well, will not really downvote: with the many upvotes the original received it's hard not to make the same mistake ... (see my comment there, in short: paintComponent _must_ fill the entire area if the panel reports being opaque)

Comment: Please do respect the Principle of `Encapsulation`, while overriding the methods of the `super Class`. `paintComponent(...)` has the Access Specifier as `protected` and not `public` :-), though I had upvoted this a long time back, I just found this mistake to be rectified, just now :-)