# Titled separator in java swing

Tags: java, swing, border, separator

I want to show titled separator in java swing application. Something like

> -------Text-------

I found some third party libraries providing this functionality:

- http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/swing/TitledSeparator.html
- http://www.jaxfront.org/member/java-core-api/com/jgoodies/forms/builder/PanelBuilder.html

But I'm interested in a way without using any third party api. Can we do this by extending JSeparator? How else can we do that?

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9533238/995822 . It uses a `TitledBorder`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you might be able to use a combination of a MatteBorder and a TitledBorder

```
MatteBorder mb = new MatteBorder(1, 0, 0, 0, Color.BLACK);
TitledBorder tb = new TitledBorder(mb, "Some Long Text", TitledBorder.CENTER, TitledBorder.DEFAULT_POSITION);
```

Comment: Great. :) And it should be `TitledBorder` and not `TitleBorder`.

Comment: Typing on iPad, always fun :P

Answer (score 4):

Use a TitledBorder. Like this for example:

```
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class TestBorder {

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestBorder.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TitledBorder titledBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Some title");
        titledBorder.setTitleJustification(TitledBorder.CENTER);
        panel.setBorder(titledBorder);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestBorder().initUI();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: It shows text to left, I want the text to be in the center of line separator.

Comment: @mark updated my code. Simply set the justification of the border.

Comment: titledBorder (aka: GroupBoxes) introduce visual noise, so don't use them - nowadays, even win ux guide cautions against using them ... @mark it's rather straightforward to implement a TitledSeperator for yourself, or extract the code from open source projects like SwingX or any other you already found

Comment: @mark exactly :-) Have a look at Karsten's (JGoodies) articles/talks

Answer (score 0):

That is simple and lower case.

```
import javax.swing.border.*;
```

then

```
BevelBorder bedge=new BevelBorder(BevelBorder.RAISED);
lbl.setBorder(bedge);
```

-----------------next border type

```
import javax.swing.border.*;
```

then

```
TitledBorder tedge=new TitledBorder(TitledBorder.CENTER);
lbl.setBorder(tedge);
```